# After upgrade to .Net 2022 receive "Cannot continue the application is improperly formatted" message

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2022

I have a Web MVC-based application. It is in fact a number of Web services + an envelope that runs them.
It was perfectly running in .Net 2017, and recently I performed an upgrade to .Net 2022.

While upgrading I chose the target framework to be 4.8 rather than to leave it as 4.6.2.
The application was perfectly built. Then I published the app to a local folder, and copied it to the web server (keeping only the previous Web.Config).

Now, when I start the application (the envelope), this is the error I receive.
It points me to the log having several types of info. First paragraph states:

> PLATFORM VERSION INFO
> Windows           : 10.0.19043.0 (Win32NT)
> Common Language Runtime   : 4.0.30319.42000
> System.Deployment.dll         : 4.8.4270.0
> built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
> clr.dll           : 4.8.4420.0
> built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
> dfdll.dll             : 4.8.4270.0
> built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
> dfshim.dll            : 10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

Could this be the problem? (CLR is 4.0-something while the target framework is 4.8?)

Another point in the log:

> ERROR SUMMARY
> Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
>
> - Activation of
>   C:\Users\micky_k\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick
>   Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\DanaDT.appref-ms| resulted in exception.
>   Following failure messages were detected:
>
> - Exception reading manifest from https://Micky.MySite.com/install/MyApp.application: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
> - The 'br' start tag on line 1 position 181 does not match the end tag of 'body'. Line 1, position 236.

What I am doing wrong?

Tried to change the target version of the pool in the IIS - but could not: the highest available option is 4.0.30319

Comment: Do not use ClickOnce deployment for an asp.net app.  Do it [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#publish-and-deploy-the-app) instead.

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant, but this is exactly what I did - published to a folder, then copied it onto the existing installation.

Comment: The presence of "appref-ms" convincingly suggests that this is a ClickOnce deployment.  Note that the ClickOnce option appears *twice* in the Publish dialogs, it reappears after you selected "Folder" in the first dialog.  Do not use it.